# When a task turn ECS does the docker run in detached mode or Foreground mode

Tags: amazon-web-services

When a task run in ECS does it docker run in Foreground or in detached mode. Is it possible to set these options in the task definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They run in `detached` mode. This is evident if you login to your container instance and **inspect the docker run command** used to launch your task.

An example from my ECS instance:

```
docker run \
        [parts not shown]
        --detach=true \
        1234455666.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/a03c-fffffecr-fffffos4q \
        python3 app.py
```

Notice the `--detach=true` option.

I'm not aware of any way to change this option. When ECS starts, there is no terminal `tty` to run in the attached mode anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you please tell me how I can inpect the docker run command which launched the task? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @kumar I use [runlike](https://github.com/lavie/runlike) tool.